# How to cook up test functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. A test function is a $C^\infty$ function with compact support. This is a rather strong restriction, for instance, no analytic function is a test function. But $\exp(-1/x^2)\exp(-1/(x-1)^2)$ is a test function.

In general I found it difficult to construct test functions with certain properties, but this seems important in proving theorems in distribution theory. Thus I wonder whether there are good ways to cook up certain test functions.

For instance, can we have a test function that pass through finite many fixed points? Can we find a test function whose derivatives have specified values at certain points? (for instance, can we construct a test function whose first $N$ derivatives vanish but the $N+1$ derivative is large?) Given a bad function, can we smooth it to be a test function (like smooth away the sharp angles of the tent function)?

The above are some of the properties I have encountered but I am also interested in other properties. So any suggestion is helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: it is not difficult to construct a $C^\infty$ function $\phi$ such that (say) $\phi(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq n$ and $\phi(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq n+\epsilon$. So just take say a polynomial $f$ satisfying your conditions and multiply it by $\phi$. Smoothing can be done by convolution with a test function with a small support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, can we have a test function that pass through finite many fixed points? Can we find a test function whose derivatives have specified values at certain points? (for instance, can we construct a test function whose first N derivatives vanish but the N+1 derivative is large?)

Yes, first apply [Whitney extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) then smoothly cut-off. For actual constructions and such, much of the work can be traced back to Charlie Fefferman; [see this article for some references](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2449).

> Given a bad function, can we smooth it to be a test function (like smooth away the sharp angles of the tent function)?

Yes, convolve it against the Gaussian (or any integrable smooth function) and then smoothly cutoff (multiply against a test function).

Comment: It seems convolving is a good way to smooth functions, but I am not sure whether this process destroy too much information of the original function. So what kind of information is preserved through this process?

Comment: It depends on what you convolve against! But convolution is multiplication on the Fourier side, so you can easily preserve any information that can be encoded with bounded frequencies, for example.

Comment: Sorry but let me make it clear. I guess you mean the information is preserved in the sense it can be decoded again from the convoluted function. But I am wondering what properties are shared by the $f$ and $f*\phi$. Also by smoothing the tent function I hope to get a function that is pretty much like the tent function but with the corners smoothed into 'round' corners so that it is a test function. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Like I said: any property that can be "computed" from knowing a bounded frequency portion of the function $f$ can be made to be shared (by choosing an appropriate mollifier) by $f$ and $f*\phi$. For the tent function, just convolve with a even (spherically symmetric) bump function of support width $\epsilon$. This will preserve linearity away from the corners and the resulting function would look very much like a tent function.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your test functions implies that they are a proper subset of the [schwartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space#Properties) functions. These functions has some nice properties such as the fourier transformation being a linear automorphism.